# guava, gwt and eclipse

Tags: gwt, guava

Is it possible to use guava in the client side code of a gwt web application? If so, how does one add guava to an Eclipse project?

I've added both the guava-10.0.1 and guava-gwt-10.0.1 jars to my build path and have added the source attachments to each but I still get this error:

> No source code is available for type
>   com.google.gwt.thirdparty.guava.common.base.Predicate; did you
>   forget to inherit a required module

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, look at your import line.  Does it look like this?

```
import com.google.gwt.thirdparty.guava.common.base.Predicate;
```

That's wrong.  Change it to:

```
import com.google.common.base.Predicate;
```

If you use completion assist in Eclipse -- Control-Spacebar -- study the list of offered completions. Don't just pick the first one.  Look to the right where it will identify the source of the completion in light grey text.  If you are looking at the thirdparty.guava one, move to the next one until you see the google.common one.

Maybe someone can give some insight into what the thirdparty.guava library is used for, whether it needs to be in the build path, and in what order Guava libraries ought to appear in the typical GWT project.

Comment: `thirdparty.guava` is a _rebased_ version of Guava (and an old one) used internally by GWT. This is the recommended way of using Guava in your projects (_rebasing_ it) so as to not suffer from version conflicts (aka _classpath hell_). You can configure Eclipse to blacklist the package for autocomplete: Java → Appearance → Type Filters, add `com.google.gwt.thirdparth.*` (you might want to add `java.awt.*` too)

Comment: Ooooh, blacklisting.  Very cool.  There is always something new to learn.

Comment: You have to include a `<inherit name="com.google.common.base.Base" />` in your gwt.xml too (and similar for other modules within Guava: Collect, Primitives)

Comment: I've now changed the import line to com.google.common.base.Predicate; and have added the 'inherit' line to my gwt.xml file but now get the error: Unable to find 'com/google/common/base/Predicate.gwt.xml' on your classpath. I've added the source jars as a source attachment in Eclipse to each of the guava jars to no avail.

Comment: Nobody said to add `<inherit name="com.google.common.base.Predicate" />` Why did you do that?

Comment: Thanks, that was a slip on my part! I did get a bunch of errors e.g. The import javax.annotation.Nullable cannot be resolved. I added jsr305.jar to my classpath and everything is now working. Thanks everyone.

Comment: @cjr: I have the same / similar problem. What version of Guava GWT did you get Predicates working with?

Answer (score 0):

Guava classes that are GWT compatible are (supposed to be) marked with the @GwtCompatible annotation. Check the source.

According to this, it is:
http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Predicate.html

You'll still need to follow Thomas Broyer's instructions to put the correct  into the .gwt.xml file.

Comment: I've added in all of the points raised above but now get the error: Unable to find 'com/google/common/base/Predicate.gwt.xml' on your classpath. I've added the source jars as a source attachment in Eclipse to each of the guava jars to no avail.

Comment: Silly question: are the relevant guava binary jars in your classpath?