# In PlayN, how can I get the HTML version of my project using Google's Guava libraries to compile?

Tags: gwt, guava, playn

I can run the Java version of my project fine by simply importing Guava libraries like so:

```
import com.google.gwt.thirdparty.guava.common.collect.ImmutableList;
```

Following the advice [here](http://groups.google.com/group/playn/msg/cccb7916d5c2d40c), I've added this line to html/pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
  <artifactId>guava-gwt</artifactId>
  <version>10.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And this line to html/project.gwt.xml file:

```
<inherits name="com.google.common.collect.Collect"/>
```

But when I try to GWT-Compile my HTML version in Eclipse, I get errors like the following:

```
[ERROR] Line 61: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.thirdparty.guava.common.collect.ImmutableList<E>; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

Comment: I did see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794014/guava-gwt-and-eclipse) about changing the classpath to com.google.common.base. Gave this a try but only seemed to make things worse.

Comment: I think it should be `com.google.common.collect` in your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may be importing the wrong class. Try replacing the `com.google.gwt.thirdparty.guava.common.collect.ImmutableList` import with `com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList`.

Here is a similar question about the `Lists` class: [Trouble with GWT and Guava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6354025/trouble-with-gwt-and-guava)

Comment: So I would then need to change all my import statements from `import com.google.gwt.thirdparty.guava.common.collect.Foo;` to `com.google.common.collect.Foo;`?

Comment: I agree that that's what you ought to do.

Comment: Yes, you were never supposed to be able to import that gwt.thirdparty thing at all. That's GWT's internal copy of ancient versions of our code.

Comment: Part of the problem I'm having is that com.google.gwt.thirdparty.guava.common.collect is the path that Eclipse seems to prefer for some reason.

Comment: I use IDEA now, but I seem to remember that Eclipse lets you configure your "favorite" imports, and specify which imports should be proposed by default for auto-completion?

Comment: Java | Appearance | Type Filters

com.google.gwt.thirdparty.*

Answer (score 2):

I selected [@eneveu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9988627/1093087) as it got me headed in the right direction. Here are more explicit instructions for enabling Guava in the HTML version of your PlayN project.

**1. Add dependency to YourGame-core/pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
  <artifactId>guava-gwt</artifactId>
  <version>11.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

**2. Right-click `YourGame-core` directory in Package Explorer window, then: Maven > Update Dependencies**

**3. For HTML5, add this line to YourGame-html/YourGame.gwt.xml:**

```
 <inherits name="com.google.common.collect.Collect"/>
```

**4. When importing, use the correct library path:**

```
import com.google.common.collect.Foo;
/* NOT: import com.google.gwt.thirdparty.guava.common.collect.Foo; */
```

I compiled the code at the link below and tested in Chrome to verify that Guava gets imported successfully:

- [PlaynDev.java](http://code.google.com/p/klenwell/source/browse/trunk/projects/java/playndev/playndev/core/src/main/java/com/googlecode/klenwell/playndev/core/PlaynDev.java?spec=svn293&r=292#16)